# Max Function of Mysql not returning maximum value of coloumn. Order by limit also not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table structure as follows:

```
                     HISTORY_CARD
     +----+-----------+---------+--------------+
     | idhistory_card |equipment_id | sr_num |    
     +----+-----------+---------+--------------+
     |  1             |      DU 201 | 9      |
     |  2             |      DU 201 | 2      |
     |  3             |      DU 201 | 12     |
     |  4             |      EXT 99 | 10     |
     |  5             |      EXT 99 | 13     |
     |  6             |      EXT 99 | 7      |
     |  7             |      EXT 99 | 9      | 
     +----+-----------+---------+--------------+
```

I would like to return maximum value of the coloumn(sr_num) for a particular euipment_id. for eg. for equipment_id = DU 201 , maximum value is 12 but with  below mentioned queries it is returning wrong value i.e 9
similarly for equipment_id = EXT 99 , maximum value is 13 but with  below mentioned queries it is returning wrong value i.e 9
. I have searched a lot in internet as well on manual but of no use till now.kINDLY help!

Queries as follows

```
SELECT *
FROM new_schema.history_card
WHERE equipment_id = 'DU 201'
ORDER BY sr_num DESC LIMIT 1
```

2 query tried

```
SELECT MAX(sr_num)
FROM new_schema.history_card
WHERE equipment_id='DU 201';
```

Comment: Is `sr_num` a string? `9` is last (max) in alphabetical order.

Comment: try `equipment_id is like 'DU 201'`

Comment: Using `like` doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Joachism, I got your suggestion. Yes sr_num is a string (VARCHAR). should i alter the table and make it Int to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson superb ........

Comment: @user3405312 Sounds like a good idea. If the value is always an integer (or null), it will fix the sorting and prevent garbage values from ending up in the table.

Answer (score 6):

The `MAX()` operation on a string value will behave according to string comparison rules, i.e. `"9" > "10"`.

The answer is to change your table definition:

```
ALTER TABLE history_card MODIFY sr_num INT;
```

Then, run the query again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM new_schema.history_card
WHERE equipment_id = 'DU 201'
ORDER BY CAST(sr_num AS UnSigned) DESC LIMIT 1
```

or:

```
SELECT *
FROM new_schema.history_card
WHERE equipment_id = 'DU 201'
ORDER BY  sr_num * 1 DESC LIMIT 1
```